Vue/Vite: __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__ is not explicitly defined
I'm getting this warning when developing locally, after updating to Vue 3.5 (I didn't before that).

VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS is not explicitly defined. You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue, which expects these compile-time feature flags to be globally injected via the bundler config in order to get better tree-shaking in the production bundle.

I have read this page, but the answers there are in the context of Webpack; I'm using Vite.
The Vue docs say that, for Vite, I need to add the following to my vite.config.js:
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    define: {
      __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: 'true' //or 'false'
    },
    ...  
})

I've done this, restarted my server, but still the warning comes.
Here's my full package.json:
{
  "name": "************",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port 1906",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 1906"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^2.0.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.53.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "flag-icons": "^6.7.0",
    "gpt-tokenizer": "^2.1.2",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "openai-gpt-token-counter": "^1.1.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.21",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.3",
    "vue": "^3.5.13",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.3.0",
    "vue-contenteditable": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.0",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vicons/antd": "^0.12.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.2.1",
    "naive-ui": "^2.40.3",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vfonts": "^0.0.3",
    "vite": "^5.4.11",
    "vite-plugin-wasm": "^3.3.0"
  }
}

What am I doing wrong?

What version did you upgrade from?  There may be more dependencies you need to update as part of the Vue 3.4 changes. Probably for your case @vitejs/plugin-vue should be upgraded to at least ^5.0.0. It would help to include your package.json with the question to be sure.

Sorry, should have added that to the question. See edit. @vitejs/plugin-vue was upgraded also, as shown.
